# Add a new user on OSX Snow Leapard Server from the command line?

Tags: mac-osx, command-line-interface, user-management

I have a Mac OSX server running Snow Leapord. I only have ssh access, and I have root access. I want to add a new user. I'm a long time unix user and was a bit suprised to see `adduser` and `useradd` not available. A bit of digging (e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855786/mac-os-x-new-users-from-command-line)) shows that it's not as straight forward.

I've tried things I've read, such as `nitool` ("command not found"), and `dscl / -create ...` ("Data Source (/) not valid"). So how the hell do I create a new user user on the command line in OSX?!

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/20702/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-5/.

Comment: Ah yes that other question is exactly what I'm looking for. However it didn't come up as a suggested question when I was searching. Bug in the search, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

[This manual](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/User_Management_v10.6.pdf) gives information on using `dscl`. Also see [this](http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/).

[Here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwinos-users/2004/Jul/msg00022.html) is some older information on `niutil`.

Comment: I found that page from osxdaily, but it doesn't work.

Comment: dscl does work - it's the standard command line way of creating users with OSX - what exactly is your error?

Comment: The error I'm getting is in the question, "Data Source (/) not valid"

Comment: Try localhost instead.

Comment: The command I ended up using is "sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user_name>". Use . instead of /.