# dscl command failing to create user - mac

Tags: mac-osx, user-accounts

I am a mac user I created a user from the terminal using dscl (I am more familiar to linux and adduser command)

It seemed to work but I can't find my newly created user under /Users, and the command `sudo su $newuser` is not recognized by the terminal. (but when I go to my mac preferences, I can see the $newuser created). How can it be ?

Comment: Could you please copy into your question the exact error message you get?

Comment: @JennyD I get su: unknown login: git

Comment: @JennyD, I added this line dscl . -create /Users/git PrimaryGroupID 80, then it worked. But I still doesn't see the '$newuser' under the /Users folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dscl` doesn't create a home directory. The part  `-create /Users/git` just mean to create an entry in the `/Users` section of the LDAP tree that manages MacOS users, this is isn't a file system path. You have to add informations about where the home directory is in the first place with additional `dscl` commands and then create this home directory manually with `mkdir`.  Also, see [this answer.](https://serverfault.com/questions/20702/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-5)